# Suppress Update to recommend settings in xcproj

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a warning in my xcproj about automatically selected architecture.
I want to keep the settings as I set them so I want to suppress this warning.
How can I suppress project warnings in xcode?